# Using Google Analytics to traking Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF) based desctop Application

Tags: google-analytics, webkit, chromium-embedded

If i developed a desktop application based  on `CEF` (or `Webkit`). It mean that my GUI is HTML. Now i want take heatmap for my App. The smartest way is using `Google Analytic` as ga.js. But ga.js available only for public site with URL like `http://***` Does anyone have idea how use GA js in local html?

Answer (score 0):

In CEF you can serve content for any scheme using resource handlers. Use CefRegisterSchemeHandlerFactory() to register scheme handler for http scheme and custom domain eg. "myapp.foo". Files can reside on local drive and be accessible through http://myapp.foo/. There is a question whether GA validates this domain. Even if, then you could register scheme handler for a real domain that you own for ex. myapp.com. Content still can be served locally for that domain using resource handler.